# Как составить запрос с двойным условием

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы:
[image: Таблица с ФИО]

[image: Таблица с характеристиками]

Нужно вывести ФИО самого тяжелого человека с ростом ниже 200.
Составил следующий запрос:

```
SELECT t1.Фамилия, t1.Имя, t1.Отчество FROM Table1 t1 left join Table3 t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t2.Вес = (SELECT MAX(Вес) FROM Table3) AND t2.Рост < 200;
```

По отдельности каждое условие отрабатывает как надо, вместе ломается когда в таблице самый тяжелый превышает 200.

Comment: `t2.Вес = (SELECT MAX(Вес) FROM Table3)` - так не ищут максимум в данном случае. Делаете обратную сортировку по весу. И ставите `limit 1`

Comment: `t2.Рост < 200` оставляете как есть

Comment: Так и думал, спасибо. Если не затруднит объясните почему так нельзя искать в данном случае?

Comment: Почему нельзя? Можно, но ответ будет некорректный. Смотрим ваш пример, `t2.Вес = (SELECT MAX(Вес) FROM Table3) ` - данным запросом вы находите запись с `id` 5, и только его. Далее вы проверяете `t2.Рост < 200`, а он 240.

Answer (score 0):

Конечный запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT t1.Фамилия, Имя, Отчество FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table3 t2 on t1.id = t2.id WHERE t2.Рост < 200 ORDER BY t2.Вес DESC LIMIT 1;
```